# Display folder in content tree not in the url

Tags: sitecore

I am new to Sitecore development. I have a simple project - which has a basic content tree structure. I want to hide folders (but not their content) from appearing in the public URL.

The Sitecore content path e.g. People/A/Alice Watson:

1. Content tree structure

[image: img_tree_structure]

So the public URL will look like this e.g. People/Alice Watson:

2. I want the URL to look like this

[image: img_URL]

I want to create folders from A-Z in order to organize names into folders. However, I do not want those A-Z folders to be publicly available in the URL. Although, I want the content of those A-Z folders to be accessible from a public URL.

1. On Sitecore, the content tree the path is : `People/A/Alice`
2. However, the public URL should be : `People/Alice`

Answer (score -1):

To achieve this you have two options.

1. Use the aliases in the Sitecore for each of the pages you want a custom URL.
2. Customize the **ItemResolver** processor in the **httpRequestBegin** pipeline along with extended LinkManager to generate the custom URL for your pages.

Thanks,
Jatin